# Android how to try multiple URL in videoView by only 1 click?

Tags: java, android, url, video, android-videoview

I'm using Android studio and I need to start a video URL in videoView, then if this video doesn't work try URL number 2 then try URL number 3 etc. by only 1 click

I tried something like this, it's work only for the first URL and the second URL then my app freeze:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String urlValue = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
    String urlNow = urlValue;
    String url2Value = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4";
    String url3Value = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/DLP_PART_2_768k.mp4";
    String ErrorVid  "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                MediaController MonController = new MediaController( this );
                MonController.setAnchorView( monPlayer );
                VideoView monPlayer=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.monPlayer);
                monPlayer.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( urlValue ));
                monPlayer.start();
            }
        } );

        monPlayer.setOnErrorListener( new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d( "video", "setOnErrorListener " );
                if (urlNow == url3Value) {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "" + ErrorVid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    monPlayer.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( ErrorVid ) );
                    monPlayer.start();
                    return true;
                }
                if (urlNow == url2Value) {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "" + url3Value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    monPlayer.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( url3Value ) );
                    urlNow = url3Value;
                }
                if (urlNow == urlValue) {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "" + url2Value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    monPlayer.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( url2Value ) );
                    urlNow = url2Value;
                }

                monPlayer.start();
                return true;

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Somebody can help me please, i'm a big noob with java.

Comment: Ok, finaly i found how to do it my self, using monPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); in Runnable timeout if ==0 go to next URL...